# Не отображается TabBar после программного перехода

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

Уважаемые знатоки! :)

Задача: авторизировать пользователя и перейти на страницу с TabBar`ом.

При переходе с помощью StoryBoard`а (Action Segue) панель TabBar`a видна. При программном переходе TabBar не отображается.

Программный переход:

```
let goToMain = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainActivity") as! MainActivity
let navBarOnModal: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: goToMain)
self.present(navBarOnModal, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Сторибоард:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: Как при программном переходе сделать TabBar видимым?(UITabBarController().tabBar.isHidden = false не помогает)

Comment: А почему бы вам не попробовать поставить Navigation Controller перед Main Activity Tab Controller и переходить уже на него?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Судя по вашему предоставленному куску кода, вы на `UINavigationController` переходите, а не на `UITabBarController`.

1. Задайте `Storyboard ID` в вашем сториборде у `Tab Bar Controller`

   [image: Storyboard ID]
2. Переход можно осуществить следующим образом:

   ```
   let storyboardName = "Main"
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
   let identifier = "MainTabBarController"
   let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier)
   present(tabBarController, animated: true, completion: nil)
   ```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно, при работе со storyboard из программного кода, вам не нужно вручную вызывать метод `instantiateViewController` для создания ViewController. Достаточно вызвать метод [performSegue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621413-performsegue) и передать в него идентификатор `segue`, заданный в storyboard.

Может быть я не правильно понимаю причину, по которой Вы используете `instantiateViewController`, но если вызвать следующий код из правильного ViewController - всё должно сработать.

```swift
performSegue(withIdentifier: "Идентификаторв Segue, заданный в storyboard",
             sender: self)
```

Comment: К сожалению программа крашится, хотя и пробовал разные "имена" идентификаторов. Хотя Ваш метод, как способ, очень понравился. Можете написать подробнее об идентификаторе в Segue, заданный в storyboard

Comment: @Lobs В Storyboard ViewController'ы соединены стрелочками. Грубо говоря, стрелочка - это Segue. Для каждого Segue можно задать уникальный идентификатор. Для этого нажмите на Segue, и в правой части Xcode у Вас появится возможность редактировать параметры. Нужно задать параметр под названием `Identifier` в разделе `Storyboard Segue`. Используйте заданное имя в коде в качестве идентификатора Segue.

Comment: Спасибо. Ваше решение тоже работает. Большое спасибо!